# OneToMany + Spring Boot + Jpa doesn't work

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, one-to-many

I'm developping a simple microservice with Spring Boot which need JPA. What I want to do is have 2 tables, Employer and Task. A employer can have 0 or n tasks. And I want to be able to access to the tasks from the employer. More over I want be able to delete a task without problems and it will be remove from employer task list :

```
@Entity
@Table(name ="employer")
public class Employer {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long id;
  private String lastName;
  private String firstName;
  private boolean isPresent;
  private double hourlyRate;
  private String phone;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy="employer", cascade= CascadeType.ALL)
  private List<Task> tasks;
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tasks")
public class Task {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long id;
  private LocalTime start;
  private LocalTime end;
  private DayOfWeek day;
  private int WeekFrequence;

  @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private Employer employer;
```

```
Task task = new TaskBuilder().withDay(DayOfWeek.SUNDAY)
        .withStart(LocalTime.of(13, 30))
        .withEnd(LocalTime.of(15, 30))
        .withWeekFrequence(1)
        .build();

    Employer employer = new EmployerBuilder()
        .withTask(Collections.singletonList(task))
        .build();

    task.setEmployer(employer);

    employer = employerService.create(employer);
```

That doesn't work.. I have the error :

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.base/java.util.AbstractList.remove(AbstractList.java:167)
    at java.base/java.util.AbstractList$Itr.remove(AbstractList.java:387)
    at java.base/java.util.AbstractList.removeRange(AbstractList.java:598)
    at java.base/java.util.AbstractList.clear(AbstractList.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.clear(PersistentBag.java:495)
    at org.hibernate.type.CollectionType.replaceElements(CollectionType.java:581)
    at org.hibernate.type.CollectionType.replace(CollectionType.java:757)
    at org.hibernate.type.TypeHelper.replace(TypeHelper.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.copyValues(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:451)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsPersistent(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:205)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:803)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:776)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingActions$6.cascade(CascadingActions.java:261)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:492)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:416)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:218)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:151)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.cascadeOnMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:519)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsPersistent(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:204)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:102)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:783)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:770)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:314)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy97.merge(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:557)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:371)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:204)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:657)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:621)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:605)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:366)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:178)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy112.save(Unknown Source)
    at cesu.planning.services.CreneauNormalService.create(CreneauNormalService.java:18)
    at cesu.planning.services.CreneauNormalService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$2c17ee16.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:769)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:747)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:366)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:747)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689)
    at cesu.planning.services.CreneauNormalService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ae2afa93.create(<generated>)
    at cesu.planning.services.EmployerService.lambda$create$0(EmployerService.java:69)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578)
    at cesu.planning.services.EmployerService.create(EmployerService.java:70)
    at cesu.planning.services.EmployerService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$a19e6211.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:769)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:747)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:366)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:747)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689)
    at cesu.planning.services.EmployerService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ca5d2b64.create(<generated>)
    at cesu.planning.EmployerTest.anotherTest(EmployerTest.java:252)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:675)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:125)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:132)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:124)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:74)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:62)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:43)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:35)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:202)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:198)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:135)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:69)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:229)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:197)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:211)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:191)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)
```

Have you any ideas ?
Thank you !

Comment: What does "That doesn't work" mean?

Comment: Sorry I update the post with the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue seems to be related to the `Adresse` property, not `Task`. Make sure that you have cascade on that as well.

The error states that you have are referencing a "transient" instance, which means an object that is not yet persisted to the database. When this happens, Hibernate will fail, since it cannot reference such an object in the database. So you need to save your `Adresse` before saving the object that references it, which is usually done by adding `CascadeType.PERSIST` (or `CascadeType.ALL`) to the variable.

The other error is due to this:

`.withTask(Collections.singletonList(task))`

`Collections.singletonList` will create an immutable list, where any mutating method (add, clear, remove, etc) will throw an `UnsupportedOperationException`. Try changing it to `Arrays.asList()` or some other way of creating a list.

Comment: For some strange reason changing the cascade option in the `@ManyToOne` annotation of `Task#employer` to `CascadeType.REMOVE` (instead of `CascadeType.ALL`) helped. I also haven't had the exact same stacktrace - I was already using an `ArrayList` (=mutable List implementation), yet I suppose I have been experiencing problems due to [hibernate bug HHH-13349](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-13349).